# Flurry (SDK 4.2.4) integration not working in Xcode 5, iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, linker, xcode5, flurry

**Context**

- Using Xcode 5
- Have added the SystemConfiguration.framework
- Have added the flurry folder into the frameworks folder of my project
- Trying to build the project for publshing

  [image]

**Error:**

[image]

**Steps taken to try to fix**

- Searched Stack Overflow
- Searched Flurry support
- Added and removed the SystemConfiguration.framework
- Cleaned and built Xcode
- Restarted Xcode

**Update**

I believe the issue was my settings for the architecture, when I set it to armv7 the compiler quit complaining.

[image]

Comment: @drc- only add flurry.h and libFlurry_4.2.3, see if their are other files present in the folder of flurry

Answer (score 0):

just add **​Security.framework​** too, and it should work.